# RGB to CMYK in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm suppposed to convert a given RGB color to CMYK format, and in case of white `(0,0,0)` I should get `(0,0,0,1)`. I've been trying this whole night but every time it crashes, could please someone tell what's wrong?

```
    rgb2cmyk :: (Int,Int,Int) -> (Float,Float,Float,Float)
    rgb2cmyk (r,g,b) = (c,m,y,k)
        | (r,g,b) == (0,0,0) = (0,0,0,1)
        | otherwise          = ((w - (r/255))/w, (w - (g/255))/w, (w - (b/255))/w, 1 - w)
                               where
                                w = maximum [r/255, g/255, b/255]
```

I get: `parse error on input '|'`

Comment: RGB (0,0,0) is black, not white. CMYK (0,0,0,1) is also black (K is black). Not that this is the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You want to say *either*

```
rgb2cmyk (r, g, b) = ...
```

*or*

```
rgb2cymk (r, g, b)
  | ... = ...
  | ... = ...
```

But not both at the same time. (Which expression would it execute?)

As an aside, you don't actually need to test `(r,g,b) == (0,0,0)`; you can just pattern-match `(0,0,0)` directly.

```
rgb2cymk (0,0,0) = (0,0,0,1)
rgb2cymk (r,g,b) = ???
```

Answer (score 1):

The section `= (c, m, y, k)` in `rgb2cmyk (r,g,b) = (c,m,y,k)` is incorrect.

When using guards, you should think of it as using something like

```
rgb2cmyk (r,g,b) = case (r,g,b) of
           (0,0,0) -> (0,0,0,1)
           _       -> ...
```

as this is what GHC will actually rewrite your guards into (this is the same with `if`, as well, which turns into `case predicate of...`).

It doesn't make sense to write

```
rgb2cmyk (r,g,b) = (c,m,y,k)
```

And then later on have:

```
case (r,g,b) of ...
```

sitting as  a floating definition in your source file.